# What Does Windows Do Before Main() is Called?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, portable-executable

Windows must do something to parse the PE header, load the executable in memory, and pass command line arguments to `main()`.

Using OllyDbg I have set the debugger to break on main() so I could view the call stack:
[image: http://puu.sh/t5vxB/3d52089d22.png]

It seems as if symbols are missing so we can't get the function name, just its memory address as seen. However we can see the caller of main is `kernel32.767262C4`, which is the callee of `ntdll.77A90FD9`. Towards the bottom of the stack we see RETURN to `ntdll.77A90FA4` which I assume to be the first function to ever be called to run an executable. It seems like the notable arguments passed to that function are the Windows' Structured Exception Handler address and the entry point of the executable.

So how exactly do these functions end up in loading the program into memory and getting it ready for the entry point to execute? Is what the debugger shows the entire process executed by the OS before `main()`?

Comment: The loader is responsible for this. It is a component of the operating system, and the way it works is such that you won't see much evidence of it in the call stack. It is otherwise too complicated to explain in a single Stack Overflow answer. Consider purchasing a book on Windows Internals if you want to learn about...well, the internals of Windows. :-)

Comment: Also, Windows loads the DLLs needed by the EXE and performs relocation. And some code from those DLLs may execute before main().

Comment: related: process startup on Linux: http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html.  Also [how to create a tiny but still runnable Linux executable](http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/software/tiny/teensy.html).  Linux does most of the process-startup stuff in the kernel than Windows does, but a dynamic binary still runs the dynamic linker and then CRT startup code in the context of the newly-execed user-space process before the C `main()` function.

Comment: Note that the OS doesn't pass the command line arguments to the executable. The C runtime library (CRT) calls `GetCommandLine` to obtain the arguments before calling `main`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

if you call [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) system internally call [`ZwCreateThread[Ex]`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntzwapi_8h.html#a8d4778b0d54da088821971642873ef51) to create first thread in process

when you create thread - you (if you direct call [`ZwCreateThread`](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntzwapi_8h.html#a8d4778b0d54da088821971642873ef51)) or system initialize the [`CONTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679284(v=vs.85).aspx) record for new thread - here `Eip(i386)` or `Rip(amd64)` the entry point of thread. if you do this - you can specify any address. but when you call say [`Create[Remote]Thread[Ex]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd405484(v=vs.85).aspx) - how i say - the system fill [`CONTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679284(v=vs.85).aspx) and it set self routine as thread entry point. your original entry point is saved in `Eax(i386)` or `Rcx(amd64)` register.

the name of this routine depended from Windows version.

early this was `BaseThreadStartThunk` or `BaseProcessStartThunk` (in case from `CreateProcess` called) from `kernel32.dll`.

but now system specify `RtlUserThreadStart` from `ntdll.dll` . the `RtlUserThreadStart` usually call `BaseThreadInitThunk` from `kernel32.dll` (except native (boot execute) applications, like `smss.exe` and `chkdsk.exe` which no have `kernel32.dll` in self address space at all ). `BaseThreadInitThunk` already call your original thread entry point, and after (if) it return - [`RtlExitUserThread`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682659(v=vs.85).aspx) called.

[image]
[image]
the main goal of this common thread startup wrapper - set the top level [`SEH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679270(v=vs.85).aspx) filter. only because this we can call [`SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634(v=vs.85).aspx) function. if thread start direct from your entry point, without wrapper - the functional of [Top level Exception Filter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681401(v=vs.85).aspx) become unavailable.

but whatever the thread entry point - thread in user space - **NEVER** begin execute from this point !

early when user mode thread begin execute - system insert `APC` to thread with `LdrInitializeThunk` as Apc-routine - this is done by copy (save) thread `CONTEXT` to user stack and then call `KiUserApcDispatcher` which call `LdrInitializeThunk`. when `LdrInitializeThunk` finished - we return to `KiUserApcDispatcher` which called `NtContinue` with saved thread `CONTEXT` - only after this already thread entry point begin executed.

but now system do some optimization in this process - it copy (save) thread `CONTEXT` to user stack and direct call `LdrInitializeThunk`. at the end of this function `NtContinue` called - and thread entry point being executed.

so **EVERY** thread begin execute in user mode from **`LdrInitializeThunk`**. (*this function with exactly name exist and called in all windows versions from nt4 to win10*)

[image]
[image]
what is this function do ? for what is this ? you may be listen about [`DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx) notification ? when new thread in process begin executed (with exception for special system worked threads, like `LdrpWorkCallback`)- he walk by loaded DLL list, and call DLLs entry points with [`DLL_THREAD_ATTACH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx) notification (of course if DLL have entry point and [`DisableThreadLibraryCalls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682579(v=vs.85).aspx) not called for this DLL). but how this is implemented ? thanks to `LdrInitializeThunk` which call `LdrpInitialize` -> `LdrpInitializeThread` -> `LdrpCallInitRoutine` (for DLLs EP)

[image]
when the first thread in process start - this is special case. need do many extra jobs for process initialization. at this time only two modules loaded in process - `EXE` and `ntdll.dll` . `LdrInitializeThunk`
call `LdrpInitializeProcess` for this job. if very briefly:

1. different process structures is initialized
2. loading all DLL (and their dependents) to which EXE statically
   linked - but not call they EPs !
3. called `LdrpDoDebuggerBreak` - this function look - are debugger
   attached to process, and if yes - `int 3` called - so debugger
   receive exception message - `STATUS_BREAKPOINT` - most debuggers can
   begin UI debugging only begin from this point. however exist
   debugger(s) which let as debug process from `LdrInitializeThunk` -
   all my screenshots from this kind debugger
4. important point - until in process executed code only from
   `ntdll.dll` (and may be from `kernel32.dll`) - code from another
   DLLs, any third-party code not executed in process yet.
5. optional loaded shim dll to process - Shim Engine initialized. but
   this is OPTIONAL
6. walk by loaded DLL list and call its EPs with
   [`DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx)
7. [TLS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686749(v=vs.85).aspx) Initializations and TLS callbacks called (if exists)
8. `ZwTestAlert` is called - this call check are exist APC in thread
   queue, and execute its. this point exist in all version from NT4 to
   win 10. this let as for example create process in suspended state
   and then insert APC call ( [`QueueUserAPC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954(v=vs.85).aspx) ) to it thread
   (`PROCESS_INFORMATION.hThread`) - as result this call will be
   executed after process will be fully initialized, all
   `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` called, but before EXE entry point. in context
   of first process thread.
9. and NtContinue called finally - this restore saved thread context
   and we finally jump to thread EP

[image]
[image]
read also [Flow of CreateProcess](https://web.archive.org/web/20151214014944/https://www.microsoft.com/mspress/books/sampchap/4354a.aspx)

Comment: Possibly silly question: is this all before the CRT code that's included by the compiler in typical executables runs?  On Linux, the user-space process entry point is normally called `_start`, and is provided by the CRT.  Only dynamic linker code runs before that in the context of the user-space process.  I'm surprised nobody has mentioned CRT code as part of what runs before the C `main` function, since that's what the question title asks (not just about reaching the CRT entry point).  Or is some of this stuff part of the normal MSVCRT or something?

Comment: @PeterCordes - all what i wrote at all not related to `c/c++` `CRT`. this is true for ALL exe in windows. however not all code writed on `c/c++` and even `c/c++` can not use `CRT` at all. if you use `CRT` your process "enrty point" is wWinMainCRTStartup or `wmainMainCRTStartup`. so code flow will be `LdrInitializeThink` -> `NtContinue` - > `BaseThreadInitThunk` -> `wWinMainCRTStartup` -> `WinMain`. all this is only windows related. about Linux - all what i know that this is OS. no more

Comment: @PeterCordes - so i describe process below/before user defined EP for process or thread is called. say i not use `CRT` - as result here `user defined EP` is my function (it any name) - it direct called from `BaseThreadInitThunk`. if you use `CRT` - your `user defined EP` is `[w]WinMainCRTStartup` or `[w]mainMainCRTStartup` in `CRT` code, which already finally called your `[w]WinMain` or `[w]main` (you must use exactly this names, when i free in name select)

Comment: @PeterCordes - "is this all before the CRT code that's included by the compiler in typical executables runs? " - yes, of course before

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.  I only mentioned Linux because that's what *I* know, so I could ask about how Windows was different.  I was confused because the question title said "before `main()`", but then nobody had mentioned CRT code as the source of some of that stuff the OP found on the stack.

Comment: @PeterCordes - I assume that OP ask about system level process(and thread) initialization. and I briefly try describe this process in **Windows** . CRT (if exist at all) - this is already application level. think here under `main` need understand `EXE` entry point . about Linux - i nothing know about this os at all, but guess that user mode execution also begin not exactly from `_start` or EXE (or how on Linux this files named ?) entry point. but this is only my guess here

Comment: This is a nice answer; I just wanted to help clarify which part of the process it's describing.

Comment: (And BTW, a statically linked Linux executable really does start right at `_start`.  I added a couple links in a comment on the question in case you're curious.  All init stuff prior to that happens in kernel space.  A dynamically linked executable is handled by running the dynamic linker (which itself is a static ELF executable) on it.   The dynamic linker runs startup code from libraries, so you can use `malloc` or `printf` from the ELF entry point of a dynamically linked binary that links libc.  But on Linux, libc is separate from the kernel: they don't share the job of process init)

Comment: @PeterCordes - hm, i guessed that  Linux also have some like windows DLL in user process space - somebody must i think export different API or all API only in kernel implemented ? probably this will be interesting for somebody who will learn Linux system programming. i however restrict self only to Windows desktop programming :)

Comment: Linux system calls like [`open(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) are available to user-space through a stable ABI using `syscall` (x86-64) or `int 0x80` or `sysenter` (i386), unlike in Windows where the only stable ABIs are the DLLs.  The libc wrapper functions around system calls are usually very lightweight; sometimes literally just `syscall` / check return value and maybe set `errno` / `ret` since the function-calling convention almost matches the syscall arg->register convention in the System V x86-64 ABI.  (But more often a thread cancellation-point check first).

Comment: See also [the 32-bit x86 Linux Hello World example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/x86/1164/getting-started-with-intel-x86-assembly-language-microarchitecture/19078/x86-linux-hello-world-example#t=201612301513405387121) on SO docs.

Comment: @RbMm You say there are some Dlls that are loaded before the end of initialization. For example, Shim DLLs loaded before TLS Initializations. Does it mean we have more limitations on what can be done on these DLLs EP? Can i create threads in DllMain of shim dll? can i QueueUserAPC? Thank you

Comment: @flyman -of course in case shim dll, which loaded before loader begin walk by static dependency dll list we have very strict limitation. in practic such shim dll can static import only from ntdll/kernel32. *Can i create threads in DllMain of shim dll* - of course, why not ? *QueueUserAPC* - no problem can

Comment: What software are you using to visualize the call stacks?

Comment: @mrexodia - here no *call stack* images, i think you mean *call tree*. i use debugger. my own. unlike *x64dbg* - it not public, and only i use it

Comment: Cool! I’d be interested if you could share how you record the traces, because x64dbg is way too slow when tracing with single step

Comment: @mrexodia - of course can, if you interesting in debugger development, but the comments here are not convenient for that. better in another way

Comment: @RbMm In LdrInitializeThunk if your EP (Eax/Rcx) is from LoadLibraryA (or RtlUserThreadStart, NtCreateThread), can one retrieve the module name being loaded by the thread? (maybe from argument?), Thanks!