# 64 bit PE injection - Suspend, inject, resume (x64 equivalent to changing EAX?)

Tags: 64-bit, code-injection, portable-executable

All,

I'm trying to figure this out by endlessly debugging applications, but I can't seem to find my answer.

In my 32bit PE injection I eventually change EAX with the new EntryPoint of the injected PE, then resume the thread. I've read that the kernel runs a call EAX at the end to get to the entrypoint(I did not see this when debugging applications, so no idea if that is really the case).

However, I can't seem to find if this is possible in x64 (Tried about all registers :)).

So all in all two questions:

1. Does the kernel actually call EAX, because I can't see that call when debugging
2. Is the same method usable of changing a register to get the new entrypoint to run in x64 or do I need to rely on e.g. CreateRemoteThread?

P.S.: I'm a security researcher :)

Comment: Oh wow. This actually solved a problem of mine. I was breaking my head over why my code wasn't working, but I was changing the instruction pointer. I didn't know EAX was called. Spent an hour debugging the disassembled version...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in x64 `RCX` register used as application defined entry point of thread. in x86 - `EAX` register used. and not kernel call this address. but kernel32.dll

Comment: Hi,

Thank you! I indeed found out that it was RCX, I had some other mistakes in my code that made it not work.

Now, I still can't find the actual assembly opcode "call RCX / call EAX" when debugging a program from start, anyone that can show me the actual command that does this is assembly from a real application?

Comment: @yannickwe87 - this is depended from windows version. in every version different code. say in win10 - set bp on `ntdll.RtlUserThreadStart(FARPROC ep, PEB peb)` - this is EP of process after `LdrInitializeThunk` and it first param (*rcx* register) is exe entry point

Comment: @yannickwe87 - you can view asm code of this 2 functions and how they call rcx [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41396596/6401656)